# allow port 3306

Tags: iptables

```
# /sbin/iptables -nvL
```

The output of above iptables command look something like this...

```
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       192.168.101.101      0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3306 state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
16810 1009K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       192.168.101.120      0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3306
```

What is the difference between these 2 lines? The second IP does not has the "state New,...". Does that make any difference? 
What all I am trying to do is allow mysql access from these IP's on default port 3306

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's related to the `-m state` match on the iptables rule. You can use `iptables-save` to see the complete rule.

`state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED` means only these three will be accepted.

`iptables` (or, more precisely, netfilter) knows about the following states:

- NEW - new connection
- ESTABLISHED - two-way traffic detected
- RELATED - traffic related to the original connection (e.g., ICMP reply related to a TCP connection)
- INVALID - traffic is invalid, e.g., a misopportune TCP segment was received
- UNTRACKED - traffic is not tracked by netfilter's `conntrack` module

As to your question: there's practically no difference between the two rules.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the source IP address and the state flags as you mentioned.

As to why your first IP is not connecting or not able to connect, when you use connection tracking in iptables you typically have a rule like:

ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

as the catchall.

The .101 rule would be just NEW.

ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.101.101             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:306